# Find the height and radius of the solid, circular base cone with an inequality

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

The given is
$${(x,y,z)}\mid 0\leq z\leq 4-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
The lowest $x$ and $y$ can be is zero, resulting in the inequality be
$$z\leq 4$$
The height and the radius is the largest $z$ can be, which is $4$.
So the radius and height are both $4$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider a section in the $x-z$ plane that is for $y=0$ to obtain

$$0\leq z\leq 4-2\sqrt{x^2} \implies 0\leq z\leq 4-2|x|$$

[image]

then the radius at the base is equal to $2$.